# Catch downloads from Chrome/Firefox/Explorer with python script

Tags: python, download-manager, pytube

I wrote a little download manager in python, and now i want to "catch" downloads from Chrome Firefox and Explorer so they will download with it, instead of each built-in download manager of the browser itself.

I want to know when each of the browsers are starting a file download, so i can prevent the default behavior and use my own manager. All i need to start a download myself is the file url of course.

I know that in the past there were popular download managers such as "Get Right" that did exactly this. I want to do something similar.

Any ideas how would i go about doing this?

Comment: it may need to build browser extension in JavaScript.

Comment: thank you can you share how i make it?

Comment: I don't know how to catch downloads. Long time ago I made only Firefox extension which uses button on toolbar to run javaScript code to search links on page and use built-in method to download it. It doesn't use external programs for this. Create extension is complex, it needs account for developers on Firefox server to certificate it. [Getting started with web-ext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext) and [examples](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples)

Comment: I found also how to use external script (python) in Firefox extension: [Native messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging) - but I never try to do it.

Comment: Thank you So much for your response its very help full for me

Comment: I added my firefox extension source code to GitHub: [firefox extension to download links](https://github.com/furas/firefox-extension-download-links)

Comment: thanks a lot can i add to my desktop application?